# "Exchange" of includes

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

As you can see, the title is a little nonsense, it's because I really don't know how to call that, but know that I tried hard to find a better title.
I hope you understand what I'm trying to say seeing the rest of the question.

Let's suppose that I have 3 classes, "A", "B", and "C".

> The class "A" includes "B" and "C".
>
> The class "B" includes "A"
>
> The class "C" includes "A"

Let's go the code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <b.hpp>
#include <c.hpp>
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from A" << std::endl;
        A a;
        B b;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <a.hpp>
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from B" << std::endl;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <a.hpp>
class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from C" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

This way, everything works fine, the output:

> Hello from A
>   Hello from B
>   Hello from C

BUT, if I do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <a.hpp>
#include <vector>
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from B" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::vector<A> garage;
};
```

I got a cascade of errors, including this one (actually, the main one, because of that one, there are others):

> error: 'A' was not declared in this scope
>
> std::vector garage;

This is exactly what I want, do you have an idea what I can do? Thank you.

**@edit - As answer to @Kerrek SB**

I tried to create separated files to each one, header and sources. (.hpp and .cpp) and the error persist.

A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <B.hpp>
#include <C.hpp>

class A
{
public:
    A();
};

#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include <A.hpp>

A::A()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from A" << std::endl;
    B b;
    C c;
}
```

B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <A.hpp>
#include <vector>

class B
{
public:
    B();
private:
    std::vector<A> garage;
};

#endif
```

B.cpp

```
#include <B.hpp>

B::B()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from B" << std::endl;
}
```

C.hpp

```
#ifndef C_HPP
#define C_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <A.hpp>

class C
{
public:
    C();
};

#endif
```

C.cpp

```
#include <C.hpp>

C::C()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from C" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <A.hpp>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

gcc

> g++ -O2 -std=c++11 -I"." -o exchange A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp main.cpp

output

> In file included from ./A.hpp:5:0,
>
> ```
>              from ./C.hpp:5,
>
>              from C.cpp:1:
> ```
>
> ./B.hpp:13:17: error: 'A' was not declared in this scope
>
> ```
>  std::vector<A> garage;
> ```

Comment: do you have #include<vector> in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, I did, it was a mistake writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the class definitions from the class member definitions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A { public: A(); };
class B { public: B(); private: std::vector<A> garage; };
class C { public: C(); };

A::A()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from A" << std::endl;
    // A a;  // no, because that's idiotic
    B b;
}

B::B()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from B" << std::endl;
}

C::C()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from C" << std::endl;
}
```

In a larger project, you would probably have separate header and source files for each of those.

Comment: I tried to create separated files, see my @edit above. - Thank you.

Comment: @SH.0x90: Fix your includes. Only include what you need in headers, and include the rest in the source files. (In particular, fix A.hpp and A.cpp.)

Comment: I removed the includes of "B" and "C" of "A.hpp" and put on "A.cpp", but I got that error: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference to `A::A()

Comment: @SH.0x90: Now you forgot to link everything... :-S

Comment: @SH.0x90: A includes B because it declares instances of B, B includes A because it uses instances of A... You have a circular reference. You need to forward declare A in B and even then I think you have to use a pointer. Your class hierarchy is the problem here.

Comment: @AndyG: Not at all. The OP's code obviously compiles, so it is fine hierarchy wise.

Comment: @AndyG - The main problem isn't the instances, but the includes and the "vector" itself, see the errors, it's about the compiler that can't find the "A" as a class declared on the scope of the program (on 'vector' part).

Comment: @SH.0x90: After the last comment you made, your program was already correct, as you can tell from the fact that it compiles. The error you have is a *linker* error.

Comment: @SH.0x90: E.g. `g++ -W -o /tmp/foo A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp main.cpp` should work.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The code you wrote works, but the splitting into separate files OP has done leads to circular includes.

Comment: With me, the error persists. The way that you sent, appeared an error that "A.hpp", "B.hpp" and "C.hpp" wasn't found. And I put the argument -I"." on the compiler and the error persists.

Comment: @SH.0x90: Change <A.hpp> etc into "A.hpp" (or update how your compiler looks for libraries)

Comment: @SH.0x90: You just told me you had an error about "undefined reference to A::A()". That isn't consistent with what you're saying now.

Comment: Yes, I changed the includes of "A.hpp" to "A.hpp", and I got that errors, but you said that I made a mess (hehe). - "Now you forgot to link everything... :-S"

Comment: Correct. So just fix your build system to issue the correct linker invokation and stop editing the code now :-)

Comment: I changed the includes of "B.hpp" and "C.hpp" of the "A.hpp" to "A.cpp", and I compiled with that arguments: g++ -W -I"." -o foo A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp main.cpp - And the error persists. - You sent to me that.

Comment: It worked, but if I need to use the "B" and "C" on the scope of the "A.hpp", what I do? For example: A(const & B input) - I got errors when I do that.

Comment: @SH.0x90: Forward-declare the class and don't include the header `class B;` And next time, please make your original question representative of the actual problem!

Comment: When I put "class B" before the declaration of "class A" I got a cascade of errors.

Comment: @SH.0x90: Look, both the answer I posted and the code I posted on pastebin compile and answer your question. If you have a different question, please post it, separately. Keep it clean, short, and representative, i.e. make it so that an answer to it will solve your actual problem. Before you do, make sure you've read other questions of "forward-declaring classes" and "resolving circular dependencies", though.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it.